# Yoast SEO blocking/re-initialising longer running process

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I have created a custom plugin, the job of which is to calls an external API to fetch data and fill in some custom tables in WordPress database.

This is really a **long-running process** (maybe over 30 minutes) and for that, I also have updated the `php.ini` configuration file accordingly. But somehow the process is failing in a time interval (around 240 seconds).

While debugging this issue I found this strange thing that - **the process is failing only when the popular plugin `Yoast SEO` is activated otherwise the job is finishing without any issues**.

Another thing to mention is in each time interval of around 240 seconds the **process is being re-initiated** again and again.

Is there anything that `Yoast SEO` is blocking or any workaround of this problem?

Comment: Have you asked Yoast about this?

Comment: No, not yet. Should I contact Yoast support?

Comment: That might help, yes. They might be able to respond quite quickly if it's something they know about.

Comment: Yoast guys didn't provide support for custom code. Hence, Any solutions?

Comment: 30 minutes is a really long time for a process to be running. There is a big chance of having other processes queued up whilst waiting for it to finish. Is it possible to arrange it to run via a cron job that repeats every few minutes but only processes a portion of the data each time?